# Se me genera 5 veces el mismo registro y no sé por que

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy generando un reporte de bitácora con FPDF  y cuando va a imprimir los datos imprime x5 un mismo registro y no se el por que esto es lo que muestra al generar el pdf:
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los primeros registros los datos son iguales pero cambia la hora, esta bien pero no deberia repetirse 5 veces lo mismo

Este es el código completo del reporte:

```
     <?php
       require('FPDF/fpdf.php');
       include_once '../CONTROLADOR/conexion.php';
       session_start();
      class PDF extends FPDF
       {
       //Cabecera de página
       function Header()
        {
       // Logo
        $this->Image('../VISTA/assets/images/gt_favicon.jpg',10,8,33);
       // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        // Movernos a la derecha
          $this->Cell(80);
        // Título
        $this->Cell(30,10,'Universidad Politecnica de los Altos Mirandinos',0,0,'C');
      $this->Ln(5);
      $this->Cell(80);
       $this->Cell(30,10,'Cecilio Acosta',0,0,'C');
     $this->Ln(5);
     $this->Cell(80);
     $this->Cell(30,10,'"UPTAMCA"',0,0,'C');
     $this->Ln(25);
      }

    // Pie de página
     function Footer()
     {
     // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
     $this->SetY(-15);
      // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
      // Número de página
      $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
      }
       //Tabla simple
        function TablaSimple($header,$usuario,$fecha,$accion,$apellido,$cedula)
      {
       $w=array(30, 30, 30, 60, 50);
      //Cabecera


foreach($header as $col)
{

     $this->Cell($w[0],6,$header[0],1);
    $this->Cell($w[1],6,$header[1],1);
    $this->Cell($w[2],6,$header[2],1);
    $this->Cell($w[3],6,$header[3],1);
    $this->Cell($w[4],6,$header[4],1);
    $this->Ln(6);
    $this->Cell(30,5,"$usuario",1);
    $this->Cell(30,5,"$apellido",1);
    $this->Cell(30,5,"$cedula",1);
    $this->Cell(60,5,"$fecha",1);
    $this->Cell(50,5,"$accion",1);

    }  

    }}

  $pdf=new PDF();
  //Títulos de las columnas
   $header=array('Nombre','Apellido','Cedula','Fecha y Hora','Accion');
  $pdf->AliasNbPages();
   //Primera página
    $pdf->AddPage();
   $pdf->SetY(50);
   $c=New conectar();
   $c->conexion();
 $limit=30;
  $sql="SELECT bitacora.usuario, bitacora.fecha, bitacora.accion,    profesor.apellido_p, profesor.cedula_p FROM     bitacora 
  INNER JOIN profesor on (profesor.nombre_p = bitacora.usuario)";

     $consulta =mysql_query($sql);

      while(list($usuario,$fecha,$accion,$apellido,$cedula)=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
     $pdf->TablaSimple($header,$usuario,$fecha,$accion,$apellido,$cedula);
      }


    $pdf->Output();
       ?>
```

Ya comprobé el Query y no es, coloque algunas columnas del `foreach` como comentarios a ver si era eso y tampoco.

Comment: se que no es una solución, pero puedes usar un ciclo for donde i va a ir aumentando y siendo colocado en lugar de [0],[1] y así usarías una sola linea, ahora bien en el select puedes hacer un group by [fecha y hora] o bien usar distinct, o bien hacer un DATEPART [enlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) y de eso puede comparar para que no salgan, pero eso ya seria complicarte mas. Revisa tu consulta con las primeras dos que he dicho. **para mi el problema esta en la consulta**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debido al codestyle de tu código no puedo verlo bien, pero el error que veo está en:

```
foreach($header as $col)
{
    $this->Cell($w[0],6,$header[0],1);
    $this->Cell($w[1],6,$header[1],1);
    $this->Cell($w[2],6,$header[2],1);
    $this->Cell($w[3],6,$header[3],1);
    $this->Cell($w[4],6,$header[4],1);
    $this->Ln(6);
    $this->Cell(30,5,"$usuario",1);
    $this->Cell(30,5,"$apellido",1);
    $this->Cell(30,5,"$cedula",1);
    $this->Cell(60,5,"$fecha",1);
    $this->Cell(50,5,"$accion",1);
}
```

Ese foreach me parece innecesario tal cuál has puesto tu código y creo que es el causante del error ya que el array header tiene tamaño de 5 elementos (de ahí las 5 repeticiones), elimina la linea del foreach y las llaves y déjalo así:

```
$this->Cell($w[0],6,$header[0],1);
$this->Cell($w[1],6,$header[1],1);
$this->Cell($w[2],6,$header[2],1);
$this->Cell($w[3],6,$header[3],1);
$this->Cell($w[4],6,$header[4],1);
$this->Ln(6);
$this->Cell(30,5,"$usuario",1);
$this->Cell(30,5,"$apellido",1);
$this->Cell(30,5,"$cedula",1);
$this->Cell(60,5,"$fecha",1);
$this->Cell(50,5,"$accion",1);
```

Si quisieras realizarlo como lo tenias hecho antes tendrias que hacer algo tipo:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $header.size(); $i++)
    $this->Cell($w[$col],6,$header[$i],1);

$this->Ln(6);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $header.size(); $i++)
    $this->Cell(30,5,"$datos[$col]",1);
```

Lo cuál bajo mi punto de vista me parece más limpio, pero ten en cuenta que tendrías que pasar los datos como array en lugar de pasarlos por individual.